# Can my Google Mini (appliance) crawl an outside server (i.e., Wordpress blog)?

Tags: wordpress, google-search-appliance

We have an old Google Mini search appliance and I am unable to get it to crawl our company blog, hosted on Wordpress. In my Crawl URLs settings, I add the [URL for the blog](https://imaginesoftwareconsulting.com), but to date, we get no search results from blog content. Am I trying to do the impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about the Google Mini, but on Google Search Appliance (Mini's bigger bro) you can check with Realtime Diagnostics if a URL can be reached, what HTTP Headers are returned and thus if a URL can be indexed. Could you check it?

My best guess is that your Mini is hosted in an internal network and can't reach your company's blog. On Google Search Appliance we would change DNS-override settings to bypass DNS-server or add a Proxy-server through which GSA would crawl the website.